# replace word under mouse in richtextbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mouse

i want to replace the current word under mouse cursor while user click on contextmenustrip dorpdownitem. i can get the word but unable to replace the word with new one here is my code, Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub tsmmutradifat__DropDownItemClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles tsmmutradifat_.DropDownItemClicked
    Dim myclickeditem As String = correct_word(e.ClickedItem.Text)
    Dim wordtoreplace As String
    If Not myclickeditem = Nothing Then
        If RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "" Then
            ' Code required
        Else
            wordtoreplace = RichTextBox1.SelectedText
            If wordtoreplace.EndsWith(" ") Then
                myclickeditem = myclickeditem & " "
            End If
            If wordtoreplace.StartsWith(" ") Then
                myclickeditem = " " & myclickeditem
            End If
            RichTextBox1.SelectedText = myclickeditem
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

ok will see, future time, when will it be

Comment: so is the `' Code required` what you need help with?

Comment: What doesn't work about the code that you have?

Comment: so is the ' Code required what you need help with? yes, 
What doesn't work about the code that you have? 

acctualy when i have both words, word to replace and word with replace but don't know how get where is cursor now, and how i can replace my word.

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. If no text is selected, there's nothing to replace. That's how spell-check functionality (which you appear to be implementing) works.

Comment: dear dear dear, just like synonyms option in MS office word, it get the text under mouse cursor and then replace with new synonym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok made it. find the below code on a forum and changed it according to my needs it a little odd but working.
In mouse move event

```
Public cursorAt As Integer
    Public wordEnd As Integer
    Public isEnd As Boolean
    Public wordStart As Integer
cursorAt = RichTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location)
       If cursorAt = 0 Then Return
       wordEnd = New Regex("[\s$]{1}").Match(RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(cursorAt)).Index
       isEnd = Not New Regex("\s").IsMatch(RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(cursorAt))
       wordStart = New Regex("[\s^]{1}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Match(RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, cursorAt)).Index
       If isEnd Then
 RichTextBox1.Select(wordStart, RichTextBox1.Text.Length)
                  Else
          RichTextBox1.Select(wordStart, cursorAt - wordStart + wordEnd)

       End If
```

and then simply replace then word

```
RichTextBox1.SelectedText = myclickeditem
```

Answer (score -1):

F6.RichTextBox1.Focus()
        SendKeys.Send(TextBox4.Text)

Answer (score -1):

I think the code suggested by user934820 can be improved.
The word boundaries are better sought with "\b". As a bonus we can ignore the end-of-text case (as it is also the word border). So the code will look like

```
wordEnd = New Regex(".\b{1}").Match(RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(cursorAt)).Index
wordStart = New Regex("\b.{1}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Match(RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, cursorAt)).Index

RichTextBox1.Select(wordStart, cursorAt - wordStart + wordEnd + 1)
```

Please, pay attention that this search will return the very last letter in the word NOT the space after it (as in original code). So increment by 1 where needed (like Selection).